# Python coverage for gstreamer threads

Tags: python, gstreamer, coverage.py, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to run python coverage on an application that uses the gstreamer python bindings to create a pipeline and I'm not able to get it to report (or collect) coverage for the user defined callbacks despite having the multithreading and threads options set in the .coveragerc file.

Is it possible to collect coverage statistics for the threads that gstreamer creates at all?

I can collect coverage for all other portions of the program but not for the gstreamer callbacks.

Comment: Have you tried the solution given here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71020663/measuring-coverage-in-python-threads

Comment: Yes, as I explained I do have thread in the concurrency section of .coveragerc. I think the issue with the gstreamer threads is that they are not created by python but by the underlying glib library.